# why android service is stopped by Android OS?

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

OK, here is my code, I'm trying to create a running service even when the app is closed.

In main activity, I have created a new button and call startMyService() to start the service as following:

```
public void startMyService(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

the Service class is simple :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("MyService", "service is running");
        final Uri uri = Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI;
        final Context x =(Context) MyService.this;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(x,uri);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();
            }
        }).start(); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("MyService", "service done");
    }
}
```

Of course, I have added the service to manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="false" android:description="@string/service_description" />
```

Now after running, I pressed the button to start the service, and close the activity, I supposed the music will be playing in the background but it stopped just after closing the activity.

How to solve this issue? How to make the service still running, and how to make it running again after an android OS destroying it?

I know there are too many topics about android services and START_STICKY

However, as you see this is not working in code above, why?

Note: This is not about playing music in the background, I used playing music because it is the simplest way to know when service is stopped, this is about how to make service keeps running in the background as supposed to be, for example, to do some task like tracking data changes from the server.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal behavior when your application target from android O, if you want to remain your `Service` you should use `startForgroundService` with `Notification`. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services)

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

Comment: so, what is the point of background services? could you please give a working example of running background service without using foreground service + notification.